# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Provider' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use useContext but constantly getting error. Here is my configuration file

```
import React from 'react'

export const ConfigurationContext = React.createContext()

export default ConfigurationContext
```

This is my App.js

```
import './App.css';

import React,{Fragment} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'


import Header from './components/header/header.js'
import Footer from './components/footer/footer.js'
import {Menu} from './components/menu/menu.js'

import {Home, About} from './components/home/home.js';
import {Editor} from './components/Editor/editor.js'
import ConfigurationContext  from './contexts/configuration';
import {useContext} from 'react'

export const config = {
  user: {
      fullname: "Jim Brown",
      id: 345
  }  
}



function App() {

    const {Provider, Consumer} = useContext(ConfigurationContext)

    Provider.value = config



  return (
    <Fragment>
       
      <Header></Header>
      <Router>
     
       
          <Menu></Menu>
          

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/contact"  >
            <Editor />
            </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        </Switch>

        
      
      </Router>
      <Footer></Footer>

      </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the error I'm getting:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Provider' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
App
src/App.js:28
25 |
26 | function App() {
27 |

> 28 |     const {Provider, Consumer} = useContext(ConfigurationContext)
> 29 |
> 30 |     Provider.value = config
> 31 |
> View compiled
> ▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

> const { Provider, Consumer} = useContext(ConfigurationContext) Returns context `value` not Provider Context Object

You can try like this. Here's the [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usecontext-demo-r8qxvg)

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// Move to seperate file if you want to
const ConfigurationContext = createContext(null); // You can pass default context as well

// Button.js
const Button = () => {
  const { config, setConfig } = useContext(ConfigurationContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.info("config.fullname changed:", config.fullname);
  }, [config]);

  const changeUserName = () => {
    config.user.fullname = 'New User'
    setConfig({ ...config });
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={changeUserName}>
      Change User Name
    </button>
  );
};

const defalutConfig = {
  user: {
    fullname: "Jim Brown",
    id: 345
  }  
}

const App = () => {
  const [config, setConfig] = useState(defalutConfig);

  return (
    <ConfigurationContext.Provider value={{ config, setConfig }}>
      <h1>React Context Demo</h1>
      <h3>
        User in Parent: { config.user.fullname }
      </h3>
      <Button />
    </ConfigurationContext.Provider>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: But, just for my knowledge, if I want to use useContext(), what changes do I have to make

Comment: You have to create Context and the Provide with value in root component and use `useContext` to subscribe the Context value. This example gives you clear Idea of how you can use `useContext` [link](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecontext-hook). Read the C component example with useContext

Answer (score 0):

Try to import with brackets :

```
import ConfigurationContext  from './contexts/configuration';
```